# In Labview how can I change the mouse pointer when hovering over one of my boolean controls?

Tags: pointers, mouse, labview

I have an interface with multiple tabs and a lot of controls. For most boolean controls I use a nice half transparent image. To better tell the user these booleans are clickable I want to change the pointer when hovering over any of these boolean buttons, not the others.

Is there a way to do this without having to individually select all the controls in the *Event Structure*? (there it takes some time to find all the boolean buttons from the list and to assign both the *Mouse Enter* and *Mouse Leave* events)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'Dynamic event registration', have look at [this NI forum post](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Nugget-of-the-week-Dynamic-event-registration/td-p/508407) that shows how to use this.

Instead of the 'Static ref', you can also feed an array of references. 
Here's a specific code snippet:
[image: BooleanEvents]
Or a more generic example shown here ([source](http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Nugget-of-the-week-Dynamic-event-registration/m-p/978489#M438444))
[image]